# How to get thumbprint of the certificate associated with a service principal using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-powershell, service-principal

I have a certificate associated with a service principal in Azure AD. How can I get the certificate name or thumbprint associated with it using powershell?

I have tried `Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipalCredential`, `Get-AzureRmADSpCredential` and `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential` commands but they return `Key Identifier` not thumbprint.

Basically I want to recognize which certificate is associated with the principal before revoking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Stanley Gong mentioned, you can use MS Graph to get it.

Here is another way, try the command as below, the `$Thumbprint` is that you want.

**Note** the `<object-id>` is the object id of your AD App(App registration), not the service principal(Enterprise application), they are different.

```
$CustomKeyIdentifier = (Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId "<object-id>").CustomKeyIdentifier
$Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works and easier too. For me, it is working with the object id of enterprise app too.

Answer (score 2):

Try the PS command below to get cert thumbprint via Microsoft Graph API :

```
$clientId = "<your Azure AD App ID>"
$clientSec="<your Azure AD App Secret>"

$appObjId = "<object ID of the app that you want to query>"

$tenant = "<your tenant ID>"
$body=@{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials";
    "resource"="https://graph.microsoft.com/";
    "client_id"= $clientId;
    "client_secret" = $clientSec
}

$accessToken=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.windows.net/$tenant/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $body ).access_token

$keyCreds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/$appObjId/keyCredentials" -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"}

$keyCreds.value.customKeyIdentifier
```

Result: 
my certs on portal : 
[image]

query result :
[image]

Pls note that make sure your app which you used for getting token with permission below so it can call Microsoft graph API to query your apps :

[image]