# How to get thumbprint of the cert associated with a service principal in AzureAD when the sp is created independently without App and Cred

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a service principal that I've creating using below powershell.

```
$sp3 = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal `
    -DisplayName "<service-principal-name>" `
    -CertValue $certValue3 `
    -EndDate ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($cert3.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString(), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'GMT Standard Time'))
```

where `certValue3` is Base64String RawCertData. This service principal works fine and I am able to get a token when using the cert.

Once service principal is created in Azure AD, how do I see thumbprint of the certificate associated with the service principal using Powershell?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58410371/3553799), but I get `Forbidden` when I try to execute Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential

I also checked the manifest in Azure Portal under the service principal that gets created under Azure Active Directory → App Registrations → <service-principal-name> → Manifest, but the `keyCredentials` node is empty

```
"keyCredentials": [],
```

Please note that when I create an application using `New-AzureRmADApplication` followed by credential `New-AzureRmADAppCredential` and then `New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal`, then I see the `keyCredentials` with `customKeyIdentifier` set to the certificate thumbprint. Sample script below -

```
$adapp = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "<application-name>" `
    -HomePage "<home-page-url>" `
    -IdentifierUris "<identifier-url>" `
    -CertValue $certValue `
    -StartDate ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($cert.Certificate.GetEffectiveDateString(), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'GMT Standard Time')) `
    -EndDate ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($cert.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString(), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'GMT Standard Time'))

New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId $adapp.ApplicationId -CertValue $certValue2 

$sp2 = New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $adapp.ApplicationId -DisplayName "<application-name>"
```

How to get thumbprint of the certificate associated with a service principal in Azure AD using powershell when the service principal is created independently without AzureRmADApplication and AzureRmADAppCredential?

Comment: Ooh that's interesting. Have you tried checking the SP object via e.g. the Graph Explorer? Https://aka.ms/ge

Comment: @juunas, yes, although i couldn't get Graph Explorer to work. I always get an empty list of applications when I invoke it. So I cannot dig further down for a specific application. :/

Comment: Did you try to get /servicePrincipals/the-objectId-from-first-command? I mean the PowerShell command should tell you the id

Comment: yes, `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/serviceprincipals/` also gives me empty list :(. Only place I can see information (or the absence of it) is on the Manifest page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following Azure AD Graph API to get the key credentials of the sp. The customKeyIdentifier in KeyCredential is the thumbprint of the certificate

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/<your teanant id>/servicePrincipals/<your sp object id>/keyCredentials?api-version=1.6
```

For example

1. Create sp and get thumbprint

```
$tenantId ="<tenant id>"
#use the goabl admin account to login 
Connect-AzureRmAccount -Tenant $tenantId

$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificateObject.Import("E:\Cert\examplecert.pfx","Password0123!", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
Write-Host "the thumbrint of cert"
$certificateObject.Thumbprint

$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificateObject.GetRawCertData())

$sp =New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "jimtestsample" -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $endDate
$context=Get-AzureRmContext
$token=$context.TokenCache.ReadItems() |Where-Object { ($_.TenantId -eq $tenantId) -and ($_.Resource -eq "https://graph.windows.net/")  }
$accesstoken=$token.AccessToken

$url = "https://graph.windows.net/$tenantId/servicePrincipals/"+$sp.Id+"/keyCredentials?api-version=1.6"

$keyCreds = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $accesstoken"}
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------"
$keyCreds.value | Select-Object customKeyIdentifier
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I don't have a token in `$context.TokenCache` where `$_.Resource -eq "https://graph.windows.net/"`. Am I missing something?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to get a token for `https://graph.windows.net/` resource in my token cache after I executed `$ctx=Get-AzureRmContext` and `Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName $ctx.Account.Id` as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2494#issuecomment-386091436). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I test your command, it should work. When using `New-AzADServicePrincipal` to create the service principal, it will create an AD App(i.e. App Registration) for you automatically, and the certificate will also appear in the `Certificates & secrets` of your AD App.

In my sample, I use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0) module, for the old `AzureRm` module which you used, it should also work(Not completely sure, I recommend you to use the new `Az` module, because the `AzureRm` module has been deprecated and will not be updated). And make sure you are looking into the correct AD App in the portal, because the `DisplayName` of the AD App could be repeated.

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=TodoListDaemonWithCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
$bin = $cert.RawData
$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)

New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName joy134 -CertValue $base64Value
```

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

[image]

Then you can use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407858/how-to-get-thumbprint-of-the-certificate-associated-with-a-service-principal-usi/58410371#58410371) you have tried, to fix the `Forbidden` error, your account should at least be the `Owner` of the AD App, or if your account has an admin role in the tenant e.g. `Application administrator`, `Groups administrator`, it will also work.

```
$CustomKeyIdentifier = (Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId "<object-id>").CustomKeyIdentifier
$Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)
```

[image]

---

**Besides**, you should note the different command combinations will lead to different results, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957666/powershell-new-azurermadserviceprincipal-getting-secret-property-doesnt-wor/59961257#59961257). So when you test it, I recommend you to use different values of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I needed a way to do this for service principles that had already been created with `AzureRm` module

Comment: Followed your script, what if the app is having more than two certs. $Thumbprint is returning the thumbprints in single line and couldn't do for each.  
$CustomKeyIdentifier = (Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId "xxxx19-4xxx-a759-a2xxxxxx4504").CustomKeyIdentifier
$Thumbprint = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CustomKeyIdentifier)