# Invoke-ASCmd does not pickup the serviceprincipal when running in an azure pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ssas

I'm trying to use the  Invoke-ASCmd within an azure pipeline (task: AzureCLI@2) without the -Credential parameter.

With the -Credential parameter it all works, but I want to make make use of the ServiceConnection service principal.
I added the Server principal to the Server Administrators (app:appid@tenantid), but it still reports an error like:

> Invoke-ASCmd : Authentication failed: User ID and Password are
> required when user interface is not available.

Comment: Please check the similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997541/invoke-ascmd-authentication-failed-user-id-and-password-are-required-when-use)

Comment: This ticket is not simular @wadezhou-MSFT . This is about running in a pipeline without the credentials (and please don't edit the question)

Comment: Thanks @Bart.  I added `azure` and `sqlserver` tag on the ticket according to the [usage of the command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps), it requires `-CertificateThumbprint`  for service principal, correct tag could engage related team to help check. The task `AzureCLI@2` has option `addSpnToEnvironment: true`, we can use variable servicePrincipalId, servicePrincipalKey and tenantId.Please check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407858/how-to-get-thumbprint-of-the-certificate-associated-with-a-service-principal-usi).